# Converting a factor "MM/YY" into a Date YYYY-MM-DD in R

Tags: r, date

I have a variable which is a date in factor format comprised by an abbreviated month and a year without century (e.g. Jun/14). I would like to convert it into a Date format which gives me the format: YYYY-MM-DD introducing to every date the day 15th.

`DN <- as.factor(c("jun/79", "jun/90", "fev/85", "jun/79", "jun/90", "dez/09", "mai/80", "fev/92", "dez/81", "dez/03"))`

`df <- data.frame(DN)`

`str(df)`

`'data.frame':    10 obs. of  1 variable:`
 `$ DN: Factor w/ 8 levels "dez/03","dez/09",..: 6 7 4 6 7 2 8 5 3 1`

`head(df$DN)`

`[1] jun/79 jun/90 fev/85 jun/79 jun/90 dez/09`
`Levels: dez/03 dez/09 dez/81 fev/85 fev/92 jun/79 jun/90 mai/80`

I´ve tried the following command:

`df$DN_Date <- as.Date(paste0(df$DN, "-15"), "%b/%Y/%d")`

But I am getting NA in all values.

`str(df$DN_Date)`

`Date[1:10], format: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Does anyone have any idea why is that happening?

I would like to get an output like this:

`Date[1:10], format: "1979-06-15"   "1990-06-15"   "1985-02-15"   "1987-06-15"   "1990-06-15"   "1980-05-15"`

Comment: You might want to tell us what locale/language you are using with your R console.  The abbreviation `dez` does not correspond to any language of which I'm aware.

Comment: It's a FAQ: month and year don't form a date. Either add a base day (the first, or fifteenth, or ...) as you did --- and convert to character before you paste. Also, consider four-digit years.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure! It is a (Brazilian) Portuguese abbreviation of months.

Comment: @Naomi you can't have a date without a day element. I suspect simply prepending `1/` to each string would allow you to parse the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that R is set to Portuguese and then either append a /15 and convert to `Date` or else convert to `yearmon` and then convert that to `Date` and add 14 days.  A third possibility is to just convert to `yearmon` and leave it as that since you are really trying to represent year/months and not dates.

```
Sys.getlocale()
# next line is only needed if above line does not show Portuguese
Sys.setlocale(locale="Portuguese")

transform(df, Date = as.Date(paste0(DN, "/15"), "%b/%y/%d"))

library(zoo)
transform(df, Date = as.Date(as.yearmon(DN, "%b/%y")) + 14)

library(zoo)
transform(df, YearMon = as.yearmon(DN, "%b/%y"))
```

Comment: Thanks, @G. Grothendieck. It worked almost perfectly, except for the fact that instead of creating a new variable into my df, I am getting a new data.frame into it: `'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:`
`$ DN     : Factor w/ 8 levels "dez/03","dez/09",..: 6 7 4 6 7 2 8 5 3 1`
`$ DN_Date:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:`
  `..$ DN  : Factor w/ 8 levels "dez/03","dez/09",..: 6 7 4 6 7 2 8 5 3 1`
  `..$ Date: Date, format: "1979-06-15" "1990-06-15" "1985-02-15" "1979-06-15" ...`

Comment: It is not good practice to modify objects but if you want to do it anyways then `df <- transform(df, ...)`

Comment: However, if I use only the command `df$DN_Date <- as.Date(paste0(DN, "/15"), "%b/%y/%d")` it will work perfectly!

Comment: Yes, but that emphasizes poor programming practice whereas what was posted would allow you to create a new data frame without overwriting the original.